# Day/Night Toggle Using Cookie to Save on Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem I'm having of course is the toggle cookie is always true once the toggle is clicked. Is there a way to check whether the toggle is active / inactive and to save that state to a cookie to then check on page refresh if dark mode should be activated?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(".toggle").toggleClass("active");
    $("body").toggleClass("night");
    $.cookie("toggle", true);
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") == "true") {
    $(".toggle").click();
  }
});
```

```css
body.night {
  background: #00151f;
  color: #fff;
}

.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #00151f;
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.toggle.active {
  background: #00151f;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.toggle:before {
  left: 0px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #00151f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.toggle.active:before {
  left: 27px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle"></div>
```

Comment: You haven't included the jQuery cookie library in your page. Once you do that your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/64o7cje0/. I'm voting to close this as a typographical error

Comment: I'm still having the same issue. If i switch from dark to light and refresh the page, the dark background is displayed due to the cookie always being set to true on click.

Comment: In which case check the console for errors as you can see from the snippet that this works fine.

Comment: I clicked the jsfiddle link you have provided. Here are the steps I am taking: I click the toggle to change to light background. I then click run. Background is now changed to dark(I do NOT want this to happen). I want whatever background is currently in view to remain the same on page refresh.

Comment: That's because you only ever set the cookie to `true`. You need to set it to false when the white state is set: http://jsfiddle.net/3x80db7f/

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you only ever set the cookie to `true`, even when changing the state. To fix this use `hasClass()` to determine what state the UI is in and set the cookie accordingly:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(".toggle").toggleClass("active");
    $("body").toggleClass("night");
    $.cookie("toggle", $(".toggle").hasClass('active'));
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") === "true") {
    $(".toggle").addClass("active");
    $("body").addClass("night");
  }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3x80db7f/)