# Saving dark mode after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that saves my dark theme after refresh:

(thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan on this post: [Day/Night Toggle Using Cookie to Save on Page Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326422/day-night-toggle-using-cookie-to-save-on-page-refresh) )

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".theme__switch").on("click", () => {
     $(".theme__switch").toggleClass("active");
    $("body").toggleClass("dark__theme");
    $.cookie("toggle", $(".theme__switch").hasClass('active'));
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") === "true") {
    $(".theme__switch").addClass("active");
    $("body").addClass("dark__theme");
  }
});
```

The only issue I find with this solution is that it flashes the original state before adding `active` to the toggle. So it flashes the original white background before adding the dark theme class. Is there a solution to avoid the flicker? or is this as good as it gets

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that your code under `jQuery(document).ready` function runs when the page fully loaded. So, you have a delay to see its result and see the flashing.
There is no choice in framework-less websites except adding a loading frame fit to the total page at first and add a code to remove it after jQuery comes ready.

Assume this for example:

html

```
<div id="overlay">
   <!-- some loading text or elements -->
</div>
```

css

```
#overlay {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background: #fff;
}
```

js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".theme__switch").on("click", () => {
     $(".theme__switch").toggleClass("active");
    $("body").toggleClass("dark__theme");
    $.cookie("toggle", $(".theme__switch").hasClass('active'));
  });

  if ($.cookie("toggle") === "true") {
    $(".theme__switch").addClass("active");
    $("body").addClass("dark__theme");
  }
 
  jQuery('#overlay').hide();
});
```